# Regex: Select and delete numbers from html tag

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex

I have a little problem. I need to select and delete all numbers and `_` from the html tag

```
<p class="BEST"><em>a Создание всего, что только когда человек  __2_2160_____</em></p>
<p class="BEST"><em>оставляет _за собой 3456 метафизическое __значение судьбы, 566_ которая проходит проверку времени_</em></p>
```

My regex seems not working:

FIND: `(?:<p class="BEST"|\G(?!^))[_]\d+\K\d+[_](?=.*?</p>)`

**The Output:**

```
<p class="BEST"><em>a Создание всего, что только когда человек</em></p>
<p class="BEST"><em>оставляет за собой метафизическое значение судьбы, которая проходит проверку времени</em></p>
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: hello @Toto I Edit the post and add the Output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to go:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:<p class="BEST"|\G(?!^)).*?\K[_\d]+(?=.*?</p>)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:                 # non capture group
    <p class="BEST"     # literally
  |                   # OR
    \G(?!^)             # restart from last match position if not at the beginning
)                   # end group
.*?                 # 0 or more any character, not greedy
\K                  # forget all we have seen until this position
[_\d]+              # 1 or more underscore or digit
(?=.*?</p>)         # positive lookahead, make sure we have end tag after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: thank you @Toto